# rails - HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError on plural has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following models:

```
User
Team
UserTeam
```

There are users and there are teams. Each team has 0 or more users, the join table is UserTeams

I want to get all teams and for each team get its users. Initially I tried for one team and get its users, like this

```
Team.find('759ccbb7-2965-4558-b254-3e437ca721aa').users
```

but rails complains about this with:

```
Could not find the association :user_team in model Team
```

This is how my Team model looks like:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :user_team
  has_many :user_teams, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_teams, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:user_id] == '0' }

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Team model:

```
class UserTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

Weird enough, if I change Team model like this:

```
has_many :user_team
```

using the singular word, it works, but I read that it has to be pluralized

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```
  has_many :users, through: :user_team
  has_many :user_teams, dependent: :destroy
```

to

```
  has_many :user_teams, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_teams
```

The `through` part should use existing association.

In your code, you specified `through :user_team`, but you don't have `has_many :user_team`, that's why rails complains.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put these inside User model:

```
has_many :user_teams
has_many :teams, through: :user_teams
```

I forgotten about these. Now it works